# Difference Between E and Object Types

Tags: java

What is the difference between E and Object types, when referring to the following example?

### Example

List interface has two methods, Add(E e) and Remove(Object obj).

How was it decided to use E or Object for each method?

Phrased another way, how would I know whether to use E or Object when writing the header of my own written method?

Comment: Do you know about generics? Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: This question is asked *a lot*. Look around a bit.

Comment: When using a generic List, it makes sense to only allow adding `E`. However, you can try to remove anything, as `remove(Object obj)` relies on the `equals(Object other)` method. So, you should use `E` where it makes more sense, and `Object` where it makes more sense depending on your method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Collections Framework sticks firmly to the rule that if an arbitrary `Object` could corrupt the collection for future use, then `E` was used; otherwise `Object` was used.

For example, removing an `Integer` from a `List<String>` is a no-op, so it is allowed; adding an `Integer` to a `List<String>` would cause a `ClassCastException` in the future, so it is not permitted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My professor previously answered something similar, but wasn't as detailed. And it was hard for me to Google/search here similar topics.